# How to use @font-face in an email?

Tags: css, email, font-face

Here's a tricky question about CSS. I have to send an email with some styles. The only way to make styles work in the email is writing them just after the tags (I cannot even write a `<style type="text/css">` because mail server ignores it). So, this is an example of what I have to do:

```
<div style="background: red;"></div>
```

For instance, that works perfect. The problem is I need to use the css @font-face query. Is there any way to include it like this?

```
<div style="background: red; @font-face { font-family: 'myFont'; src: url('myURL'); }"></div>
```

Note: obviously last line is not working at all.

Here is a similar post with an answer:

[Can @fontface be used within a tag? (for email signature reliability)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069424/can-fontface-be-used-within-a-tag-for-email-signature-reliability)

But I cannot use an external style sheet or copy it in a style section, because it will not work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have a look at this : http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3044/does-font-face-work-in-email

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467381/can-outlook-2010-use-a-web-font-in-an-html-email/21485767#21485767). After much testing it is the best supported technique I came up with for webfonts.

If you want it only for a signature, say out of Outlook - There is no technique I'm aware of. Even though you can call it inline, all the techniques to actually add/call the webfont URL need to be in a `<style>` tag. It is like trying to call an external style sheet inline... Don't think it is possible.

Also, in html email, you need to use the 6-digit hex code when declaring colors. Try `background-color:#FF0000;`